# How to install qt-createor with the special qt sdk's path

Tags: qt, qt-creator

- I first installed "Qt libraries 4.8.4 for Linux/X11 (225 MB)" in "`/usr/local/Txxxx/qt4`" path,
- Then installed "Qt Creator 2.6.2 for Linux/X11 32-bit (60 MB)",

But it default qt sdk's path is "`/usr/share/qt`"

I got a following error:

> "xxxxxx.h":No such file or directory;

But this file is under `/usr/local/Txxxx/qt4` directory;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a kit in Qt Creator with the Qt that you installed: http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qtcreator-2.6/creator-targets.html

Comment: Need Qt SDK when install Qt Creator,but My Qt SDK isn't local default path,so I cann't install Qt;you said that I have already installed Qt Creator,but I have not qt creator.

Comment: Need Qt SDK when install Qt Creator,but My Qt SDK isn't local default path,so I cann't install Qt;